# Tomee / OpenEJB migration from JBoss

Tags: jboss, openejb

I am newby to TomEE+. I just try to deploy my existings EJB (large application with about 100 jars) from JBoss, just copying in webapps.
It seems to work but when I start my client, It tries to call my ejb and fails due to bad port :

Client configuration :
    java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory
    java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces
    java.naming.provider.url=localhost:1099

How can I change the openejb port listening ? Do I have many change to switch JBoss to TomEE ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How do you call EJBs from client? TommEE is not full profile certified Java EE6 server so if you are using something what is not in web profile, there's some chance that it's not yet implemented.